# How to check if an user voted but to be impossible to see for whom?

Tags: p2p, bitcoin, voting, voting-system, blockchain

## Blockchain Voting System

### How current system works

- Users are allowed to vote after their identity is confirmed by an authority.
- Votes are collected and counted by an authority.
- The person who has the most votes, have the power for ~4 years, then we vote again.

#### Problems

- The elected person can become irresponsible and corrupt within the ~4 year period and the citizens can't do much about this, they just have to wait until the ~4 years will expire.
- A lot of money are spent for election campaigns because everybody is trying to get power for ~4 years.

### How the new system works

- Users are allowed to vote after their identity is *registered in blockchain and confirmed by an authority*.
- Votes are stored anonymously on a blockchain.
- *It's possible to check if an user voted, but it's impossible to check for whom he gave his vote.*
- Votes are "realtime" (a new block is mined every XX minutes) and can be displayed on a billboard in the center of the town, so the elected person will watch it every day and work hard to maintain people's trust.
- Users are allowed to change their vote every week (Sunday).
- If the user didn't changed or updated his vote for X weeks, the vote is expired and deleted. That way the citizens will be more active (also this fixes the problem with dead users)

#### Problems

- How to implement: **It's possible to check if an user voted, but it's impossible to check for whom he gave his vote** ?
- How to implement users?

  - Authentication: biometric or just a key give by an authority. It must be very simple and secure for non technical users.
  - New user creation - new people who reach 18 years
  - Anybody must be able to verify if the user who voted is a real person (prevent flood from corrupted central authority who has the ability to create new users)

https://gist.github.com/moldcraft/e2eb508e10b9ae7e70d1

Comment: Does the central authority has the knowledge of the vote, I mean do they know for whom the vote was given? If the central authority knows about this piece of information, then they can easily manipulate the votes. Corruption is close related to the central authority. I think it is the biggest issue here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. A voter produces a statement of how they wish to vote.
2. The voter blinds the vote, attaches the blinded vote to a proof of their identity, and signs it.
3. The central authority receives the blinded vote and verifies the signature. If the signature is correct, the central authority signs the [blinded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_signature) vote.
4. The voter unblinds the signed vote and uploads it to a repository or adds it to a blockchain anonymously.
5. The central authority must be able to produce one signed, blinded vote for every unblinded vote produced. So if there are 50,000 votes signed by the central authority collected, the central authority must be able to produce 50,000 blinded votes signed by voters.

The signed, blinded votes show who voted. The unblinded votes show how many votes each candidate or proposal got. There is no way to map the blinded votes to the unblinded votes, so there is no way to tell who voted for what.

Comment: 1. On blockchain are stored unblinded votes signed only by the central authority? 2. How to check if an user voted and when?

Comment: 1. Correct. 2.The central authority must present a signed, blinded vote for each unblinded vote. If you want that to include a timestamp, you can do that. You can also require the central authority to publish the signed, blinded votes immediately into a blockchain if you want.

Comment: 1. So the central authority signature for blinded vote can be applied on unblided vote? 2. There is no way to check if central authority signature on unblinded vote is the same as on some blinded vote and make a link between vote and user?

Comment: @moldcraft The central authority signs the blinded vote. The voter then unblinds the vote, preserving the signature. Neither the central authority, nor anyone else but the voter, can figure out which unblinded vote corresponds to which blinded vote. That's how blind signatures work -- the signer does not know what they're signing.

Comment: The central authority signs the blinded vote - at this point it knows that the signature, let's say, `b123...7f` coresponds to user `john smith`. Now the user submits his unblided vote toghether with that signature `b123...7f` on blockchain and the central authority knows that that unblinded vote belongs to user `john smith`. Or I am missing something?

Comment: @moldcraft Read step 4 carefully -- he doesn't submit the unblinded vote together with the blinded signature. That wouldn't work since the blinded signature signs the blinded vote. He takes the signed, blinded vote and unblinds it, and that's what he submits. The blinded signature is *never* put together with the unblinded vote or the unblinded signature.

Comment: I thought I understood how it works but now I am stuck, I don't know how to implement it. Too much to explain, the comment section is not enough. I will try to reformulate and better describe the problem (with pictures).